# Nest js getting session data from the memory store

Tags: node.js, nestjs, backend, express-session

I was wondering if there is a method to access directly the session memory store and get the session data for a particular session id i'm using express-session package with the nest js freamwork.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you found answers to your question since then. I came up with the following technique which is using NestJS DI system.

---

#### Background

- According to NestJS official [session documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/session#session) you can register a session middleware inside your `main.ts` file.
- According to ExpressJS official [session middleware documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html) (the `session(options)` on top of the page), you can specify the session store that will be used by the middleware. If its omitted then the default MemoryStore is used.

All the session stores shares a common interface, so its a interchangeable part of your application, which makes a good candidate them to be provided as an injection token by a module. See a [list](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html#compatible-session-stores) of session stores advised by expressjs.

---

#### Implementation details

Create a new module (e.g. SessionModule), then add it to the imports array in your AppModule.

Next we create the injection token for the session store.

```js
import { MemoryStore } from 'express-session';
import { SESSION_STORE } from './session.const';

@Module({
   providers: [
      {
         provide: SESSION_STORE,
         useFactory: () => {
            return new MemoryStore();
         },
      },
   ],
   exports: [SESSION_STORE],
})
export class SessionModule {}
```

where `session.const.ts` contains a simple export statement

```js
export const SESSION_STORE = 'SESSION_STORE';
```

Now inside `main.ts` file, you can get a reference to the session store to setup session middleware.

```js
const store = app.get(SESSION_STORE)
app.use(express.session({
    store,
    // ... other options
}
));
```

If you want to access sessionStore in other services / controllers you have to import the SessionModule to the module that declares them.

ex.

```js
@Module({
   imports: [SessionModule],
   controllers: [UserController]
})
export class UserModule {}

// inside user controller you can inject a reference
// to the session store in the constructor
@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
    constructor(@Inject(SESSION_STORE) private sessionStore) {}
}
```

With the sessionStore property you can get any stored session with the following method documented in the linked expressjs documentation. `store.get(sid, callback)`